# ST3: how to find console.log in all files and comment/uncomment it using macro

Tags: macros, replace, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Hi i want to comment all console.logs in all files in a particular folder

heres what i have done

```
[{
    "args": null,
    "command": "copy"
}, {
    "args": {
        "extend": false,
        "to": "bol"
    },
    "command": "move_to"
}, {
    "args": {
        "characters": "//"
    },
    "command": "insert"
}]
```

it will comment current line but i dont know how to search console.log in all files macro dont save find/replace before deploying web on production server

Updated:
actually when in production i want all console.log to be commented and when in dev all console.log to be uncommented, in all files. I have more than 40 pages. I cant do it manually. Is there any plugin or macro for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open **`File -> Search`**, and enter `console.log` in the search field. Press <kbd>Find All</kbd> to select all the instances in the current file. Then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (Windows or Linux) or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> (OS X) to comment out all those lines.

Unfortunately, this only works for one file at a time. Macros can't handle multiple files or views, you'd need a plugin for that. If you have an absolute ton of files to change that can't be done by hand, let me know and I'll see what I can whip up.

Comment: actually when in production i want all console.log to be commented and when in dev all console.log to be uncommented, in all files. I have more than 40 pages. I cant do it manually. Is there any plugin or macro for that?